# Understanding react native props and deep linking

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have `product list` and `product info` pages. When user select a product in list page, I `passProps` product data from product list to product info page so I don't have to re-query the same data from database. In the mean time, my product info page allow deep linking.

if user deep linking to product info page, where should I passProps data?
in custom URL or query again data from database?

note: i'm using firebase as database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow recommended by many including Flux/Altjs is to always keep your state outside of your components. Now, how to apply that concept to your case?

- `ProductList` listens to `ProductStore`
- `ProductInfo` listens to `ProductStore`
- `ProductStore` has an array of `products`
- `ProductStore` has a `active_product` which is equal to the product clicked, that exist in `products` array that was used to generate the list of products in the `ProductList` component.

Scenario 1: user visits 'product list' page, clicks on a product, the product info is shown. The data was fetched when the products where loaded to show the list, then the `active` product was set in the store, so `product info` page doesn't have to load anything.

Scenario 2: user visits `product info id=1` page, `product info` component checks if `active_product` has data, it doesn't since the page just loaded, so query the DB for data and put it int `active_product`.

Comment: Is it same if my database is firebase?  I forgot to mentioned that

Comment: it doesn't matter the database implementation. The above is more of  a general way of doing things, independent of the specifics of your app. That's the power of SOLID principles (google the acronym)